# Harvester query to identify databases where the ID has reset

Tags: mysql

I need a MySQL query to identify if a database has a table where the auto-incremented ID has reset back to 0. This can result in non-unique rows for those IDs. I'm not sure how to write this. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

A_I does not go back to zero; it hits the max for the datatype and then is stuck there.  This leads to errors on `INSERT` that you should be checking for.

This will get you the `SELECTs` necessary to do the investigation:

```
SELECT  CONCAT("SELECT  MAX(", column_name, ") AS max_id, '", data_type, "' AS type, ", (column_type LIKE '%unsigned%'), " AS 'unsigned'  FROM  ", table_schema, ".", table_name, ";"
              ) AS stmts
    FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS`
    WHERE extra LIKE '%auto_increment%' ;
```

Sample row:

```
 SELECT MAX(AId) AS max_id, 'int' AS type, 1 AS 'unsigned'  
 FROM alerts.action;
```

Running that sample gets:

```
+--------+------+----------+
| max_id | type | unsigned |
+--------+------+----------+
|      4 | int  |        1 |
+--------+------+----------+
```

The next step is to understand that `int` `unsigned` has a max of 2^32-1, and compare that to the `4`.

All of this could be done in a long stored procedure, or in some application code (I leave that as an exercise to the reader).